# webviews open default browser

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when the url is https the web views works fine but as soon as it changed to http it opens default browser. here is my code
package com.a404gameproductions.insomniax;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Insomniax_WebView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://insomniax.biz");
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Insomniax_WebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: @Mike M: I think he want to keep 'https' on WebView

Comment: i want the http to work as the https. am a novice

Comment: @geniuskidkanyi : I saw that you set your variable `mWebView` two times, Please remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this 2 lines in your code -

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());﻿

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination URL. However, you open your links on your WebView by adding these lines.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Insomniax_WebView);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: when my link changes from https to http it opens browser